# remove tag parent who contain a specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delete all `<p>` who contains `<br>` tags. I'm using this jQuery code but it's wrong -- the code doesn't want delete `br`, I need to delete parent who have `br`.

need your help, I saw many remove script but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#singlecomment54').find('br').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="singlecomment54" class="ql-container ql-disabled">

  <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="false">
    <p>ghjkghjk</p>
    <p>GHJK</p>
    <p>GHJK</p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p><br></p>
  </div>

  <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>` that contain *solely* `<br/>` tags, or `<p>` that contain `<br />` tags mixed with other content too?

Comment: If that's all your `.each()` is doing, you could simplify your code down to `$('#singlecomment54').find('br').parent('p').remove()` or even `$('#singlecomment54 p > br').parent().remove()`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.parent`... as in :

```
$(this).parent('p').remove();
```

Code snippet:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#singlecomment54').find('br').each(function() {
    $(this).parent('p').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="singlecomment54" class="ql-container ql-disabled">

  <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="false">
    <p>ghjkghjk</p>
    <p>GHJK</p>
    <p>GHJK</p>
    <p>sdf<br></p>
    <p>sdf<br></p>
  </div>

  <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: who thanks, not so far.. , I give you a +1 in few minues ( I can't for now )

Comment: @KeVin glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer as correct as well

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing the paragraph.  You're removing the break tag itself:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#singlecomment54').find('br').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

```css
p:before { content: 'P: '; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="singlecomment54" class="ql-container ql-disabled">

   <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="false"> 
   <p>ghjkghjk</p>
   <p>GHJK</p>
   <p>GHJK</p>
   <p><br></p>
   <p><br></p>
   </div>

   <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
</div>
```

If you want the closest ancestor paragraph to be removed, you can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#singlecomment54').find('br').each(function() {
        $(this).closest('p').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
p:before { content: 'P: '; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="singlecomment54" class="ql-container ql-disabled">

   <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="false"> 
   <p>ghjkghjk</p>
   <p>GHJK</p>
   <p>GHJK</p>
   <p><br></p>
   <p><br></p>
   </div>

   <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this firts get all br tags Them get one level up parent "p" and remove it `$("br").parent("p").remove ()`

Or you can iterate the list of br objects an apply each item .parent ("p").remove()